# There is no available StoreManager of type "appengine".

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

There is no available StoreManager of type "appengine". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"

I'm receiving the error above when I attempt to persist a object. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My POM and jdoconfig are below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">
    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>entprog</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookapi</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <appengine.target.version>1.9.17</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to persist to GAE/Datastore yet don't put "datanucleus-appengine" jar in the CLASSPATH. The message is clear

Answer (score 0):

There is no available StoreManager of type "appengine". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"